# How can I access views in activities within a TabActivity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity

I've got a `TabActivity` containing other activities intended to split up a form. The `TabActivity` has in its layout a button intended to collect the data from all the form-related views across all the activities contained within the `TabActivity` and store it. The problem I'm running into is that the `TabActivity` doesn't appear to have access to these views; when I call `findViewById()` with one of them, I get a `NullPointerException`.

The documentation seems sparse about exactly how `TabActivity` works with respect to controlling the activities it contains. If it destroys an activity when switching from it to a different one, the situation I'm in would make sense. I'd like to know the best approach for accomplishing the goal described above.

src/com/vendor/MyTabActivity.java:

```
public class MyTabActivity extends TabActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_tab_activity);
        final Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // NullPointerException happens here
                String fieldValue = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_field)).getText().toString();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

res/layout/my_tab_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost">
    <LinearLayout>
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"/>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/save_button"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

src/com/vendor/NestedActivity.java:

```
public class NestedActivity extends Activity {  
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nested_activity);
    }
}
```

res/layout/nested_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <RelativeLayout>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/text_field"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from these two lines in `MyTabActivity`...

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_tab_activity);
```

...and...

```
String fieldValue = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_field)).getText().toString();
```

...although you obviously know the `findViewById(R.id.text_field)` is what's causing it.

Using `findViewById(...)` only works when trying to access UI elements which have been inflated as part of your current Activity. As there isn't a `TextView` with the resource id of `R.id.text_field` in the `my_tab_activity.xml`, it's never going to work.

Accessing activities which are tab content from the `TabHost` / `TabActivity` is tricky. My suggestion would be to use `SharedPreferences` which can be accessed from everywhere in your app. Once a `TextView` (or any other user-input item) is changed, save it to a `SharedPreferences` using a 'key' which identifies which activity/tab it came from. From then on, the `TabActivity` can collate the data easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference to activities running inside of the tab activity using [getLocalActivityManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html#getLocalActivityManager%28%29) or [getCurrentActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html#getCurrentActivity%28%29). For the activity object you get back you can do activity.findViewById() to get a reference to a view inside of the specific activity. But to point out TabActivity has been deprecated and you should be using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) to do what you are looking for. If you are targeting a version of Android earlier than 3.0 you can use the [compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) to access fragments.